# Is every reason reducible to a sequence of tautological statements?

Tags: logic, tautology

I think of tautological statements as those statements which when explained should *repeat* themselves, and should intuitively explain the reason. For example, A = A *because* 'A *is equal to* A'; Dog is either black or not black *because* Dog can be either black or not black.

It seems to me therefore that tautology, in a manner of speaking, mirrors our *intuitive* reasoning because a mere instance of repeating it explains the statement itself.

*Comments on self-explanatory nature of tautology are required*. *What can be said about this phenomenon?*

Also is every logical explanation reducible to such self-evident tautologies (combined with logical operations)?

Comment: With *tautology* do you mean trivial, uninformative ? If so, I think that we cannot equate explanation with tautology. Human beings learn a lot of new things during their life, exactly through explanations: reading, school, etc.

Comment: If with *tautology* do you mean the technical term used in the semantics of propositional logic, then the statement is FALSE. Many logical and mathematical truth are not tautologies (i.e. provable in propositional calculus).

Comment: Which one would I be referring to when I say that tautology explains *itself*? I want to say that structure of tautology explains itself; although I am not sure exactly what structure I would be talking about -but something very much like its logical structure (problem remains as to what I mean by its 'logical' structure!)

Comment: I would not say trivial or obvious at first sight; but something which helps to explain. Something which is validated alone by its logical structure, and our ability to understand it by reason, and *not* by facts of the world. Where facts are only fillers; substance is in how one fact is related to another. A chain if you would like to think.

Comment: I do not recall anyone understanding a statement after it is repeated if they did not get it the first time. Just because something is intuitive, or self-evident, or we can not not come up with an independent reason  to justify it, does not mean it "explains" itself. I am not sure that "self-explanatory nature of tautology" is a phenomenon that exists, but one can certainly derive all tautologies from "self-evident" Boolean axioms. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Conifold But it appears to me that a self-evident statement can be 'self-evident' only by virtue of itself. Shouldn't a complex proposition P be reducible to atomic parts S1, S2, ..., Sn, forming a sequence, such that when analysed, they express logical validity of P by just themselves i.e. S1, S2,...Sn, *together* are able to express logic of assertion of P?

Comment: I do not think I understand what "self-evident only by virtue of itself", "express logical validity of P by just themselves", or "together express the logic" mean. Perhaps this refers to the idea of "analysis" on the model of Aristotle's subject-predicate logic with its canonical decomposition into primitives, and the naive hope it created of deriving everything from definitions. That does not extend to propositional logic, let alone predicate calculus, and in practice amounted to making "definitions" that are axioms in disguise.

Comment: @Conifold It might. Would you be kind to point out why such 'naive' approaches don't work anymore in modern logic? I have observed that many of my questions revolve around what has been described as 'naive' and 'old school' thoughts; perhaps they don't stand the rigor of modern practice. However I am perturbed if such naive approaches preserve some sort of logical holism -something we might be giving up when making theory more rigorous (modern). Of course I am not claiming or asserting, just a thought.

Comment: The problem is not with rigor but with expressive means. Aristotle's logic only allows very limited types of statements (syllogisms) and inferences. Those can be analyzed into "atomic parts", and inferences interpreted as "explanations" (Aristotle even rejected some valid syllogism figures because they were not "explanatory"). But once you add propositional connectives and multi-place predicates the inferential structure becomes much more complex, and conclusions are no longer "contained" in the premises, as Kant put it. Peirce had an interesting commentary on it somewhere.

Comment: @Conifold Can you refer me the text where Kant discusses this? Help much appreciated.

Comment: Introduction to CPR, where he introduces the analytic–synthetic distinction, see [conceptual containment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction#Conceptual_containment). Peirce originally thought it could be extended to general logic, and built his original system of categories on that basis, which he had to scrap after de Morgan's paper on reasoning with multi-place predicates.

Comment: You may be interested in Leibniz's theory of conceptual analysis, which is similar in spirit to yours, see [De Risi's book, esp. 3.2](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319198620):"*The deduction itself is thus performed... through an analysis of the subject and the predicate into their conceptual constituents, which is effected through a system of definitions... Leibniz thought that the conceptual analysis of the notions involved in a statement may eventually arrive at a set of concepts that cannot be further analyzed (the simple ideas)*". But analysis falters beyond subject-predicate form.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. There are multiple sorts of tautologies, each with a different purpose.

One is the [Law of Identity](http://Law%20of%20Identities) which is phrased as "A is A", and is essentially an axiom in reasoning. For instance, in mathematics, an equation like x+y+z=5 may eventually result in a statement such as 0=0 in which the mathematician can be assured that he has followed the rules appropriately and has shown the two sides are indeed equal. This is related to a [coherent theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_theory_of_truth). Reducing an argument to the law of identity shows no contradiction.

Another type is a [rule of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(rule_of_inference)) which is used to reduce one proposition to a simpler form. When one says "A and A is here" or "A or A is here", and the same A is being discussed, then it reduces to "A is here". These are examples of [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). Rather than just showing that something is itself, this seeks to remove redundancy from propositions, and thus is used to show an equivalence among propositions.

Strongly related to tautology is identity, such as [Leibniz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles) which states two things are the same thing if all of their properties are the same. Anything is itself? Consider the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) where it is not necessarily clear that a thing is itself over time if it is modified.

In regards to tautologies being meaningful, you said:

> For example, A = A because 'A is equal to A'; Dog is either black or not black because Dog can be either black or not black.

Bravo! This is actually a very important notion of truth known as the [semantic theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth). 'A is equal to A' is true because A is equal to A, or more generally 'P' is true [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) 'P' is true. This apparently tautological statement is made to avoid [Russell's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) by separating a language from a metalanguage.

Do tautologies have meaning? Sure, otherwise why would anyone use them. How they have meaning differs in their use. That is to say the pragmatic use of the statements makes the statements true despite their apparently vacuous propositional notions. See the [pragmatic theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_theory_of_truth).

Now, ultimately, where meaning and truth comes form is a source of no little controversy, and one of the most famous philosophers of the 20th century, [Ludwig Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein) is infamous for moving from a correspondent theory of truth in his first great work, [*Tracatus Logico-Philosophicus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus), to anticipating what cognitive science has demonstrated about the [embodied origins of intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embodied_cognition) in his second work, [*Philosophical Investigations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations).

Ultimately your question is dead-center, because you are asking about where does the truth of proposition come from. This is subject of the famous [Agrippan Trilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma) which is a philosophical argument from Antiquity that aims to show that truth and meaning ultimately are derived from outside the rational discourse itself, the same conclusion Wittgenstein arrived at when he declared people merely play language games. This is a proposition consistent with what psycholinguistics says about the origins of meanings (that it comes largely from outside of language itself). Ray Jackendoff in his *Foundations of Language* says "direct connection between a language in the mind and objects in the world is severely problematic. I conclude that the proper formulation of reference is as a relation between linguistic expressions and the world as conceptualized by the language user". This is a position also held in *Philosophy in the Flesh* by Lakoff and Johnson.

It should be noted that many philosophers, even in the analytic tradition, are ignorant or skeptical of the claims of this emerging school of philosophical thought, since it attacks traditional notions of [objectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivity_(philosophy)), a near universal set of presumptions about meaning and truth. These notions go to the heart of the debate between [realist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_realism) and [idealist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealism) positions.

Comment: -1: you've misconstrued the correspodance theory of truth. In fact, such a theory is never tautological ...

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah Oh, thanks, I made a mistake. I'll amend.

Answer (score -1):

This is just plain rubbish as pointed out by the mathematician David Hilbert in his book, *Geometry and the Imagination* - he did not call it 'Geometry and the Tautology'. In fact, he spends a great deal of time and trouble in the early part of the book giving mathematicians who fetishise the tautology a good kicking.

In fact, it's deductive thinking that he comes down most savagely on, which leads me to suppose had he come across a tribe of mathematicians that eulogised the tautology - he'd say hang the lot of them!

It's the imagination he eulogises, which in the mathematical sciences, he calls induction (and not to be confused with mathematical induction, which in his typology of mathematical thinking, he would call deductive).

Comment: Your answer is equally useless (unless you provide some concrete reasons). Of course, you may be right. But I am looking for explanations, not judgements.

Comment: @Ajax: That is an explanation as well as a summary of a judgement. If you want the full explanation then I can't suggest anything better than to read Hilberts book.

Comment: @Ajax: What would your rather I do when a stupid question is asked - mollycoddle it? Give it sweeties? If you want better answers then ask better questions rather than 'useless' ones ...

Comment: I wouldn't have asked the question if it appeared to me as 'stupid'. One can certainly see that. Your assertiveness helps; I should try to look from another perspective.

Comment: @Ajax. This is a profoundly deep question because it gets at the notion of truth, identity, and meaning. See my response.